# Subdomain vs different domain for different clients

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app that I plan on selling to multiple customers. Each customer will have his own frontend, backend and database. The app will be hosted on firebase. I don't plan on having significant "per client" customizations to the app. I'm trying to decide whether it's acceptable in terms of security, to have a separate subdomain for each client (e.g. client1.myapp.com) or should I go for separate domain for each client (client1myapp.com).

Does the subdomain approach in any way affect the way in which I write security rules? Or is this taken care of by default, given that each client will have his own firebase project.

I'm leaning towards subdomains, as I expect it to be easier to maintain.

Comment: Hi does my posted answer helped ? Is there anything which I can make correction in it, so it can be helpful to you ?

Comment: Hi Rohit, I'm sorry but you answer isn't helpful. Please don't take this the wrong way, but your answer is imprecise and not applicable to the question. It feels you just copied it from somewhere without proper understanding, trying to ramp up your karma. I suggest you try to be a bit more concise and try to avoid buzzword inapplicable phrases such as "Provides a structured and organized way to manage client-specific resources", unless you give an example. Best regards

Comment: "whether it's acceptable" is really asking for our opinion and without understanding the entire use case, there's no answer. Do you need separate subdomains or even separate firebases? Maybe? What's the use case? Do clients have shared data? Is any personal or other private information being stored? Have you considered a [multi-tenant](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-authentication) approach? A lot more datapoints would be needed to accurately answer but I would suggest a SO Search [multi-tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5Dmulti-tenant)

Comment: Can you provide more info so that we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Following approaches might work for you.

Using subdomains or separate domains for each client in your app :

#### Benefits:

- Provides a structured and organized way to manage client-specific resources.
- Helps maintain separation and isolation between client instances.
- Allows for easier maintenance and scalability.

#### Security considerations:

- Security rules in Firebase are based on the Firebase project and its configuration from GCP, not from the domain or subdomain.
- Each client can have its own Firebase project, with a unique project ID and API key.
- Security rules are scoped to the specific Firebase project, ensuring data isolation between clients.
- Subdomains help organize and distinguish client instances but don't directly impact security rules.

#### Implementation:

- Create separate Firebase projects for each client.
- Define client-specific security rules within each Firebase project.
- Use Firebase hosting configuration to map subdomains to their corresponding Firebase projects. For more information on connecting to subdomains you can go through [**Connect a custom domain**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain)
- Maintain a single codebase while providing separate client environments.
- Manage all the projects through [**Configure multiple projects**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects)